# Does the value of a indexed field affects performance?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
create type size_type as enum('tiny', 'small', 'tall');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people ( 
    size size_type NOT NULL 
);
```

Imagine it has tons of data. If I index the **size** field, the length of the strings on the enum will affect the performance of the database when executing queries? For example, **('ti','s',ta')** will be more performatic than **('tiny', 'small', 'tall')** or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Good question. I wouldn't think so since I believe they are represented as `INT` internally (I may be wrong). Anyway, it's better if someone who's expert on the inner details of PostgreSQL -- like @LaurenzAlbe -- responds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter at all. Under the hood, `enum` values are stored as `real` (4-byte floating point numbers), regardless of the label text.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.8) offers the following explanation:

> An enum value occupies four bytes on disk. The length of an enum value's textual label is limited by the `NAMEDATALEN` setting compiled into PostgreSQL; in standard builds this means at most 63 bytes.
>
> The translations from internal enum values to textual labels are kept in the system catalog `pg_enum`. Querying this catalog directly can be useful.

Comment: I didn't even think it would be described in the docs.

Comment: Thank you both Laurenz and Impaler! <3